# Showing that the sequence of functions $f_{n}(x) = x^{n}$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ - Solution verification

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

There is already a solution to this question on the site, but I just wanted to verify that my thought process to arrive at my solution was correct as well.

The question asked to show that the sequence of functions $f_{n}(x) = x^{n}$ does not converge uniformly to the function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &,\ 0 \leq x < 1 \\
1 &,\  x = 1
\end{cases}
$$

To work this out I approached things by using the case where $x \in [0,1)$. And as such I am left to find a scenario that staisfies:

$$|f_{n}(x) - f(x)| = |x^{n} - 0| \geq \epsilon$$

After algebra I construct an $x$ that would satisfy my desired result:

$$x \geq \sqrt[n]{\epsilon}$$.

So this means that as long as I choose any point $x$ in the interval I would arrive at this conclusion. Now this is satisfied as long as $0 < \epsilon < 1$. If $\epsilon > 1$ then choose my $x$ such that it satisfies $x \geq \sqrt[n]{\epsilon - \lfloor \epsilon \rfloor}$ (there is definitely an easier choice but I forgot what it was and I'm curious to see it).

So to now prove the statement, I would begin by choosing an $\epsilon$. For this let's say that $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Letting $x$ be such that it satisfies the property: $x \geq \sqrt[n]{\epsilon}$, this then means:

$$|f_{n}(x) - f(x)| = \bigg|\bigg(\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n}}\bigg)^{n} - 0 \bigg| = \frac{1}{2}   \geq \epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$$

Which would satisfy the negation of the definition of uniform convergence.

Is this the way to approach such a question? Also how to treat the case of $\epsilon > 1$ more cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are going to apply your approach to $\varepsilon=\frac12$, there is no need for you to say what you would do if $\varepsilon>1$. And, if you felt that need, then you would also have to say what you would do if $\varepsilon=1$.

Other than that (and the fact that apparently you use the letters $n$ and $N$ for the same thing) it is correct.

Comment: made all those "n" the same now...thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach:  The function $f$ is not continuous.  If the convergence were uniform, it would be.

Comment: the contrapositive of uniform convergence theorem, nice